# Where/how is information on Collections stored on the Kindle Paperwhite?

Tags: kindle-paperwhite, collections

Where is the (local) information about Collections stored on the Kindle Paperwhite? Any additional information about the format/structure would also be appreciated.

On my older Kindle ("3 keyboard"), there was `/system/collections.json` which seemed to be storing the information about Collections, but is not used on the Paperwhite.

When I first got the Paperwhite, I asked Amazon support how I can transfer my Collections information, and they said that the only way to do this is by syncing the old Kindle with the associated Amazon account and then syncing the new device with the same account. (The problem is that this method will only sync documents downloaded through Amazon.)

However, the information about Collections must also be stored on the device somewhere (otherwise, it would not be possible to update Collections on a device without it being connected to the Internet), so I'm trying to find out where/how.